# How to request a url with % witouth making it be %25?

Tags: html, forms, encode

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

```
%   %25 %25
```

I have this form with a hidden input that has the value something like "%56756%234" but when i submit the form it replaces my % for %25 and it goes like "%2556756%25234" and doesn't work, is it possible to send the original value with form?

Comment: What does "and doesn't work" mean?

Comment: If the submitted value is URL encoded % > %25 then on the server is should be URL decoded %25 > %

Comment: Probably the right thing to do is decode it on the server. Usually this is already done for you by a web thing.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, i forgot to say that

Comment: Unless the value you need to send is already URL-encoded – and it doesn’t look like that’s the case – this is impossible and makes no sense to begin with. There’s probably something about the task you aren’t explaining or don’t understand. Without knowing more details or what the server is running, there’s no way to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

URLs can't contain `%`, because it is used as the escape character for forbidden symbols so they encode it with `%25` and this is how it should be. Most methods that interact with URLs automatically encode and decode it. If yours doesn't the framework or language you are using probably has a method to do it manually.

For JavaScript that would be:

[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

If you use PHP for your backend it would be:

[`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: The thing is, i don't have access to the server side, i need it to go like that or it doesn't work :c

Comment: Then your serverside has to decode it for sure or you just can't send any prohibited characters

Comment: I've seen other site doing it a form without hidden inputs and putting that somehow in the url i just don't know how

Comment: The method to send it depends on how your server has to receive the data, do you have control over that?